# What are the .mlf, .mlt and .mtc files generated by pdflatex?

Tags: table-of-contents, auxiliary-files, minitoc

On a particular document `pdflatex` is generating a large number of files with the extensions `.mlf`, `.mlt` and `.mtc`, e.g `document.mtc`, `document.mtc1`, `document.mtc2`, and so on. These dozens of files are rapidly cluttering the working folder and making the location of real assets somewhat difficult.

I work with TeXlipse, that is usually able to store this sort of file in a temporary folder. However, with these particular extensions it fails to do so, possibly due to [a bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/texlipse/bugs/379/).

What are exactly these files? Can their generation be avoided somehow?

**Update**: As suggested in the comments this document apparently uses `minitoc` (started from a rather extensive template); right before the table of contents are these commands:

```
\dominitoc
\dominilof
\dominilot
```

Is there any way to instruct `minitoc` either to clean these files or tuck them away somewhere else?

Comment: Are you using minitoc?

Comment: I would say those 'must' be `minitoc` generated files

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I confirme : Mini List:( Figure, Table), Mini Table of contents, for chapters 1,2,...

Answer (score 4):

**Update** Providing a small hack code that uses a different `\jobname`, but this will shift all generated files to a directory path named in `\minitocpath` yet.

The `minitoc` package generates a bunch of files to perform its designed tasks.

In the following explanation `X` stands for `lof`, `lot` or `toc` and `Y` means a either a chapter, part or section number, depending on context.

The basic concept of `minitoc` are the chapter-wise `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` commands, called `\minitoc`, `\minilof` and `\minilot`.

Each of those commands create one file per chapter, named `\jobname.mtcY`, `\jobname.mlfY` and `\jobname.mltY` -- those files are written even if there is no `\miniX` command used.

The list of files written by `minitoc` is also stored in `\jobname.maf`.

Since `minitoc` provides the `\partX` and `\sectX` commands as well those commands produce `\jobname.ptcY`, `\jobname.plfY` and `\jobname.pltY`, respectively `\jobname.stcY`, `\jobname.slfY` and `\jobname.sltY`. Those commands are mutually exclusive!

A shifting of those files to some place by `minitoc` is not possible, at least not without modifying/patching the code of `minitoc`.

Here is a sample file for `minitoc`, creating `\jobname.mtc0` to `\jobname.mtc3` etc.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% Must be placed before `minitoc` is loaded!
\newcommand{\minitocpath}{%
  minitocdump/% Change the name of the directory. 
}

\makeatletter
\let\jobname@@orig\jobname
\def\jobname{\minitocpath/\jobname@@orig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{minitoc}

\dominitoc
\dominilof
\dominilot


\begin{document}
\faketableofcontents
\fakelistoffigures
\fakelistoftables
\chapter{First chapter}
\minitoc
\minilof
\minilot
\section{First section}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\caption{A local figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A local table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\minitoc
\minilof
\minilot
\section{Second section}

\chapter{Third chapter}

\section{Third section}
\end{document}
```

... and a similar version for `\parttoc` etc.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% Must be placed before `minitoc` is loaded!
    \newcommand{\minitocpath}{%
      minitocdump/% Change the name of the directory. 
    }

    \makeatletter
    \let\jobname@@orig\jobname
    \def\jobname{\minitocpath/\jobname@@orig}
    \makeatother

\usepackage{minitoc}

\doparttoc
\dopartlof
\dopartlot


\begin{document}
\faketableofcontents
\fakelistoffigures
\fakelistoftables
\part{First part}

\parttoc
\partlof
\partlot

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\caption{A local figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A local table}
\end{table}


\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\caption{A local figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A local table}
\end{table}


\part{Second part}


\parttoc
\partlof
\partlot

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Second section}

\chapter{Third chapter}

\section{Third section}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\caption{A local figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A local table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]